# Python Structuring Nested Try Except Statements

Tags: python, nested, escaping, try-catch

I have a list of ints called companyNumbers. These are being checked against an online API to test they are valid.

Some company numbers have an incorrect first digit, so I would like to check the number, then if an HTTP error is received (Indicating an invalid number) to recheck the number minus its first digit.

If this is again invalid then the number is written to an error sheet, otherwise it is stored in correctNumbers.

```
for companyNumber in companyNumbers:
    try:
        r = s.profile(companyNumber).json()
    except HTTPError:
        try:
            r = s.profile(companyNumber[1:]).json()
        except HTTPError:
            errorSheet.write(i, 0, companyNumber)
    else:
        correctNumbers.append(r)
```

I am not sure how to structure my try/except/else statements. I need the else statement to activate if either of the try blocks are successful. Currently the nested try block does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try` runs the code under its nest until an error occurs.  So you should put the output into that layer as well.

```
for companyNumber in companyNumbers:
    try:
        r = s.profile(companyNumber).json()
        correctNumbers.append(r)
    except HTTPError:
        try:
            r = s.profile(companyNumber[1:]).json()
            correctNumbers.append(r)
        except HTTPError:
            errorSheet.write(i, 0, companyNumber)
```

Comment: This looks fishy to me. There is repeated code `correctNumbers.append(r)`.